# how to initialize application asynchronously in angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asynchronous, initialization

I am writing an angular app that will need some **asynchronous** code to run during the bootstrap phase. Let's say that this pahe includes collecting several AJAX call responses. As the resources are being requested, there is an overlay icon shown (*waiting for data*). After all of the requests are done, the application is ready to start working. The question is: **how to do this correctly in angular?**

The things I've found in the web so far seem to be hacky, such as:

- http://xcellerant.net/2014/10/30/initializing-global-variables-and-synchronous-ajax-calls-in-an-angular-xpages-application/ - here the author uses jQuery to run $.ajax synchronously, which is 100% what I **don't** want to do, because of obvious reasons.
- https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data - here the author removes the `ng-app` from HTML to bootstrap the application manually. This is better then above, but still, quite hacky.

I am looking for a convenient and clean solution. In **backbone** (or anything built on top of it), for example, you may simply run several ajax requests inside `initialize` method. Backbone relies on jQuery afterall - or something complaint - so just collect them all asynchronously using `$.when(list-of-promises)` and fire an event that will asynchronously bootstrap the whole app. This is purely modular. And there are no hacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to delay bootstrapping your app.

You use $http service to request data.  $http methods return promises.  You can use the $q service's $q.all() method to wait until all the $http promises have resolved.

Something similar to this:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-if="!Initialized">
        Overlay (waiting for data)
    </div>
    <div ng-if="Initialized">
        Application
    </div>
</body>


angular.module('app', [])
.run(function($rootScope, $q, $http){
    $rootScope.Initialized = false;
    $q.all({
        firstRequest: $http.get('/someresource'),
        secondRequest: $http.get('/someotherresoruce'),
        thirdRequest: $http.get('/athirdresource')
    }).then(function(results) {
        $rootScope.resource1 = results.firstRequest;
        $rootScope.resource2 = results.secondRequest;
        $rootScope.resource3 = results.thirdRequest;
        $rootScope.Initialized = true;
    });
});
```

Note, this is to demonstrate how to wait for multiple $http requests concurrently and to change from a "loading" to a "ready" state.  Using $rootScope is generally frowned upon as a way to share data across controllers.

Comment: I think this answer provides the simplest and most Angular way of accomplishing this. If you really really need to delay initialization, you can provide a set of dependencies for your controller when you define your routes. Note this applies to the controller and not the overall app bootstrap. Take a look at the resolve property for the route parameter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: @JoeEnzminger can you tell more about _Using $rootScope is generally frowned upon as a way to share data across controllers_? I don't want to follow bad practice - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Generally you want to encapsulate shared data in angular services.  Items on $rootScope are global, which makes implementing controllers that depend on $rootScope data difficult to unit test.  For services that need to be initialized, the service can have an init() method that returns a promise that is resolved when the service is ready, and you can use that promise in the same way you use the promise returned by $http in my example.